# Allotropes of carbon conductivity

Tags: physical-chemistry, carbon-allotropes

Give reason how can i made diamond a conductor by doping  charcoal and graphite which are allotrope of Carbon act as conductor. Whereas diamond which has a different crystal structure act as an insulator

Answer (score 1):

In charcoal and graphite, conjugated pi systems (the molecule orbital configuration found in carbon-carbon double bonds) act as the conductive band, where electrons can move freely.

In diamond, all bonds are SP3 hybrid bonds (the molecule orbitals found in single bonds). Therefore, no pi systems and thus no conductive band exists.

**Edit** (after  Jon Custer's comment, thanks): [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_properties_of_diamond#Electrical_properties): Except for most natural blue diamonds, which are semiconductors due to substitutional boron impurities replacing carbon atoms, diamond is a good electrical insulator, having a resistivity of 100 GΩ·m to 1 EΩ·m[28] (1011 to 1018 Ω·m). Thus it is possible to dote diamonds with boron to make them more conductive.

Comment: Diamond is a wide band gap semiconductor that can be doped to make devices. Not as well as silicon, that is true.